# How to persists image use for Eclipse Decorator

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-pde

I'm creating a custom image decorator which will decorate project/file explore according to the several logic. For a example lets take Findbugs plugin it will scan the project and decorate project/files image which are having errors, even Eclipse IDE restarts it will maintain the FindBug image status of the project/file. Like that how can I maintain the persit state of the image decorator even Eclipse IDE restarted?

Is there any good tutorials for that? I found following link for decorators
https://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Decorators/decorators.html

Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no standard mechanism for persisting data for decorators.

Things like FindBugs are most likely using Markers defined using the `org.eclipse.core.resources.markers` extension point and created using the `IResource.createMarker` API. Markers are persisted.

Views such as Project Explorer have a standard decorator which shows decorations for markers which extend the `org.eclipse.core.resources.problemmarker` marker.